# do we have auto revoke permission in ios?

Tags: ios, iphone, permissions

In android we have **auto revoke permissions**, and permissions will be revoked if user doesn't use app for few months,

Do we have similar feature in iOS which will automatically revoke permissions already granted by user?

Comment: Not that I am aware of. Any reason why you would want this?

Comment: No. This is not a feature of ios